# Can you put a link in an accordion or not?

Tags: css, accordion

I've installed a simple CSS accordion, and it works fine.

I've heavily adapted this one: `http://codepen.io/pollardld/pen/lthAF` (actually, one very similar although I don't have its source address).

Question: there's text at the top (closed position) that you click and it opens. I want that, but I want to put some text at the left (the site name and link) that will link and not open the accordion. Is this even possible, though (without using an absolute-positioned link overlayed with Z-index, which is my fallback if no experienced coder here knows a cleaner, cheaper solution.

Thanks

Reference code (not necessary to this question but required by Stack because I linked to Codepen:

```
 <h3>Accordion</h3>
<div class="accordion">
<!-- span to target fix closing accordion -->
<span class="target-fix" id="accordion"></span>

<!-- First Accoridon Option -->
<div>
<!-- span to target fix accordion -->
<span class="target-fix" id="accordion1"></span>

<!-- Link to open accordion, hidden when open --> 
<a href="#accordion1" id="open-accordion1" title="open">First Accordion</a>

<!-- Link to close accordion, hidden when closed -->
<a href="#accordion" id="close-accordion1" title="close">First Accordion</a> 

<!-- Accorion content goes in this div -->
<div class="accordion-content">
<p>Accordion 1 Content</p>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Second Accoridon Option -->
<div>
<span class="target-fix" id="accordion2"></span>
<a href="#accordion2" id="open-accordion2" title="open">Second Accordion</a>
<a href="#accordion" id="close-accordion2" title="close">Second Accordion</a>
<div class="accordion-content">
<p>Accordion 2 Content.</p> 
</div>
</div>

<!-- Third Accoridon Option -->
<div>
<span class="target-fix" id="accordion3"></span>
<a href="#accordion3" id="open-accordion3" title="open">Third Accordion</a>
<a href="#accordion" id="close-accordion3" title="close">Third Accordion</a>
<div class="accordion-content">
<p>Accordion 3 Content</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>


<div class="accordion blue">
<!-- span to target fix closing accordion -->
<span class="target-fix" id="accordion"></span>

<!-- First Accoridon Option -->
<div>
<!-- span to target fix accordion -->
<span class="target-fix" id="accordion4"></span>

<!-- Link to open accordion, hidden when open --> 
<a href="#accordion4" id="open-accordion4" title="open">First Accordion</a>

<!-- Link to close accordion, hidden when closed -->
<a href="#accordion" id="close-accordion4" title="close">First Accordion</a> 

<!-- Accorion content goes in this div -->
<div class="accordion-content">
<p>Accordion 1 Content</p>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Second Accoridon Option -->
<div>
<span class="target-fix" id="accordion5"></span>
<a href="#accordion5" id="open-accordion5" title="open">Second Accordion</a>
<a href="#accordion" id="close-accordion5" title="close">Second Accordion</a>
<div class="accordion-content">
<p>Accordion 2 Content.</p> 
</div>
</div>

<!-- Third Accoridon Option -->
<div>
<span class="target-fix" id="accordion6"></span>
<a href="#accordion6" id="open-accordion6" title="open">Third Accordion</a>
<a href="#accordion" id="close-accordion6" title="close">Third Accordion</a>
<div class="accordion-content">
<p>Accordion 3 Content</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>


<div class="accordion red">
<!-- span to target fix closing accordion -->
<span class="target-fix" id="accordion"></span>

<!-- First Accoridon Option -->
<div>
<!-- span to target fix accordion -->
<span class="target-fix" id="accordion7"></span>

<!-- Link to open accordion, hidden when open --> 
<a href="#accordion7" id="open-accordion7" title="open">First Accordion</a>

<!-- Link to close accordion, hidden when closed -->
<a href="#accordion" id="close-accordion7" title="close">First Accordion</a> 

<!-- Accorion content goes in this div -->
<div class="accordion-content">
<p>Accordion 1 Content</p>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Second Accoridon Option -->
<div>
<span class="target-fix" id="accordion8"></span>
<a href="#accordion8" id="open-accordion8" title="open">Second Accordion</a>
<a href="#accordion" id="close-accordion8" title="close">Second Accordion</a>
<div class="accordion-content">
<p>Accordion 2 Content.</p> 
</div>
</div>

<!-- Third Accoridon Option -->
<div>
<span class="target-fix" id="accordion9"></span>
<a href="#accordion9" id="open-accordion9" title="open">Third Accordion</a>
<a href="#accordion" id="close-accordion9" title="close">Third Accordion</a>
<div class="accordion-content">
<p>Accordion 3 Content</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  background: #734f79;
  font-family: 'Flamenco', serif;
}

h3 {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

/*_________________  Accordion
________________________________________
.accordion, .second-accordion {
  position: relative;
  margin: 60px auto;
  width: 80%;
}

[id*="open-accordion"], [id*="close-accordion"], [id*="open-second-accordion"], [id*="close-second-accordion"] {
  background: #00a486;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  line-height: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 99%;
}

[id*="close-accordion"], [id*="close-second-accordion"] {
  display: none;
}

.accordion a, .second-accordion a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding-left: 2%;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: none;
}

[id*="open-accordion"]:after, [id*="close-accordion"]:after, [id*="open-second-accordion"]:after, [id*="close-second-accordion"]:after {
  content: "";
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 15px;
  z-index: 999;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.target-fix {
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
}

.accordion-content {
  background: #fff;
  height: 0;
  margin: -1px auto 0;
  padding: 0 2.5%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 90%;
  transition: all 0.1s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease;
}

.accordion span:target ~ .accordion-content, .second-accordion span:target ~ .accordion-content {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.accordion span:target ~ [id*="close-accordion"], .second-accordion span:target ~ [id*="close-second-accordion"] {
  display: block;
}

.accordion span:target ~ [id*="open-accordion"], .second-accordion span:target ~ [id*="open-second-accordion"] {
  display: none;
}

.accordion span:target ~ [id*="close-accordion"]:after, .second-accordion span:target ~ [id*="close-second-accordion"]:after {
  border-top: 10px solid #333;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
}

*/

.accordion {
position: relative;
margin: 60px auto;
width: 100%;
}

[id*="open-accordion"], [id*="close-accordion"] {
background: #87D3B7;
border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
line-height: 40px;
height: 40px;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
width: 99%;
}

[id*="close-accordion"] {
display: none;
}

.accordion a {
color: #fff;
font-size: 1.25em;
font-weight: normal;
padding-left: 2%;
text-decoration: none;
text-shadow: none;
}

[id*="open-accordion"]:after, [id*="close-accordion"]:after {
content: "";
border-left: 10px solid transparent;
border-right: 10px solid transparent;
border-top: 10px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
position: absolute;
right: 5px;
top: 15px;
z-index: 999;
transform: rotate(-90deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.target-fix {
display: block;
top: 0;
left: 0;
position: fixed;
}

.accordion-content {
background: #fff;
height: 0;
margin: -1px auto 0;
padding: 0 2.5%;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
width: 90%;
transition: all 0.1s ease;
-webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.1s ease;
}

.accordion span:target ~ .accordion-content {
display: block;
height: auto;
padding-bottom: 25px;
padding-top: 10px;
}

.accordion span:target ~ [id*="close-accordion"] {
display: block;
}

.accordion span:target ~ [id*="open-accordion"] {
display: none;
}

.accordion span:target ~ [id*="close-accordion"]:after {
border-top: 10px solid #FFFFFF;
transform: rotate(0deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.accordion.blue [id*="open-accordion"],.accordion.blue [id*="close-accordion"] {background: #87C3D3;}
.accordion.red [id*="open-accordion"],.accordion.red [id*="close-accordion"] {background: #D38791;}
```

Comment: While it's interesting to see a pure CSS accordion, I wouldn't recommend using this. Two anchors that hide/show to display one heading, that's poor HTML. I would find a better one (which probably uses JS.)

Comment: I've used a number of pure CSS hidden menus. They have their disadvantages, but overall I prefer them, especially when they're very simple. I also wouldn't consider anything bad code in particular if it works smoothly and isn't heavy code-wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to side-step using an `<a>` altogether.

**New Window:**

```
<!-- Link to open accordion, hidden when open --> 
<a href="#accordion1" id="open-accordion1" title="open">First Accordion <span data-href="http://www.google.com.au" onclick="window.open(this.getAttribute('data-href')); return false;">Google</span></a>
```

**Same Window:**

```
<!-- Link to open accordion, hidden when open --> 
<a href="#accordion1" id="open-accordion1" title="open">First Accordion <span data-href="http://www.google.com.au" onclick="document.location.href = this.getAttribute('data-href'); return false;">Google</span></a>
```

Employing a little Javascript will avoid disentangling existing functionality.

Again, as I stated in my comment:

> While it's interesting to see a pure CSS accordion, I wouldn't recommend using this. Two anchors that hide/show to display one heading, that's poor HTML. I would find a better one (which probably uses JS.)

.. I still don't recommend this accordion.

Comment: Thanks. Nice solution.

Comment: What would cause this to open in the same window?

Comment: Edited answer for same window.